# UI mapping in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I was just wondering if there is any easier ways to assign values to html controls from an object or vice versa in asp.net. To do it manually is just painful

```
//assign value
txtFirstName.Text = person.FirstName;

//retrieve value
var p = new Person();
p.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
```

However to do it "pragmatically" is also kind of painful because it's got so many cases as you can see in [this code](http://code.google.com/p/dam-simple-architecture/source/browse/trunk/src/DSA/DSA.Helpers/UIMapper.cs), which is based on the ideas from [this article](http://www.emxsoftware.com/Domain+Driven+Design/Hooking+your+Domain+Model+and+UI+Layer).

```
if ((ctrl as TextBox) != null)
{
    var txt = ctrl as TextBox;
    if (p.PropertyType == typeof (string))
        txt.Text = p.GetValue(data, null).ToString();
    else if (p.PropertyType == typeof (decimal))
        txt.Text = p.GetValue(data, null).ToString();
}
else if ((ctrl as DropDownList) != null)
{
    var dropdown = ctrl as DropDownList;
    dropdown.SelectedValue = p.GetValue(data, null).ToString();
}
```

I couldn't find any other clever ways to automate this. Can some one point me a clever way of doing it because the form I am doing has literally more than 100 fields I just don't want code it manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like good old fashioned DataBinding might help?

[Binding to Business Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178368.aspx)

[ObjectDataSource example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178538.aspx)

[Binding to Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178361.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

We use [mygenerationsoftware](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/) to generate the basic UI - DB mapping to avoid doing this manually and then where-ever some customization is required, we change the code manually.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve data on postback you can go back to the Request object and just do

string[] _ArrayOfFields = new string[]{"FirstName"};

string _FirstNameValue = Request.Form[_ArrayOfFields[0]];

etc

You can then do something similar when setting values to your controls

((TextBox)Page.Controls[Page.FindControl(ArrayOfFields[0])]).Text = "New Value";

Comment: your method won't work with any html controls other than text box (i mean the assignment bit)